# Create a new Date column from another datetime field - spark scala dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to a create date field from an existing dateTime field in the dataframe and getting error

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.time.{LocalDateTime, ZoneOffset}
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val tempdf = Seq(Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.of(2021, 3, 8, 18, 0))).toDF("Date1")
tempdf.withColumn("newDate",Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.of(year(add_months($"Date1",-1)),month(add_months($"Date1",-1)),1))).show()
```

expected output : newDate should be "2021-2-1" (YYYY-MM-dd format), basically go back to previous month and year and day 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `LocalDateTime` on a Spark column. You need to use Spark SQL methods:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.time.{LocalDateTime, ZoneOffset}
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val tempdf = Seq(Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.of(2021, 3, 8, 18, 0))).toDF("Date1")

tempdf.withColumn("newDate", 
    to_date(
        concat_ws("-",
            year(add_months($"Date1",-1)),
            month(add_months($"Date1",-1)),
            lit(1)
        )
    )
).show()

+-------------------+----------+
|              Date1|   newDate|
+-------------------+----------+
|2021-03-08 18:00:00|2021-02-01|
+-------------------+----------+
```

A neater way is to use `trunc`:

```
tempdf.withColumn("newDate", add_months(trunc($"Date1", "month"), -1)).show()
+-------------------+----------+
|              Date1|   newDate|
+-------------------+----------+
|2021-03-08 18:00:00|2021-02-01|
+-------------------+----------+
```